# this->field vs. this.field in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, operators, this, field

How do lines `(2)` and `(3)` even compile in the following C++ class, given that `this` is a pointer, so should need `->` notation to access fields (as seen in line `(1)`)? ([Source](https://github.com/vmoglan/pcl-java/blob/76a3d7a047b976c1a15fdf7e06968adcf859e5aa/src/main/c/sptr_wrapper.h))

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

template <typename T>
class sptr_wrapper
{

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<T> sptr;

public:
    template <typename ...ARGS>
    explicit sptr_wrapper(ARGS... a) 
    {
        this->sptr = boost::make_shared<T>(a...);
    }

    explicit sptr_wrapper(boost::shared_ptr<T> sptr) 
    {
        this->sptr = sptr; // (1)
    }

    virtual ~sptr_wrapper() noexcept = default;

    void set_from_sptr(boost::shared_ptr<T> sptr) 
    {
        this.sptr = sptr; // (2)
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<T> get_sptr() const
    {
        return sptr; // (3)
    }
};
```

Comment: #3 is perfectly fine.  #2 should not compile... are you by chance testing with a Microsoft Visual C++ compiler that's more than a couple years old and does not support two-phase template instantiation?  If you are, then the error will be detected when you try to call `set_from_sptr()`... it's not actually compiled unless you use it only parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you believe that the reason this compiles is because nothing really gets compiled here?

The shown code defines a template.

A template does not become "real" until it instantiates a class. Only at that time the compiler gets a closer look at the template, and attempts to figure WTF it's doing.

Sure, when defining a template the compiler makes a half-hearted attempt to parse the template, but only barely enough to satisfy itself that the template consists of some plausibly-looking C++ code.

If you add some additional lines to the shown code you'll get the compilation errors you were yearning for:

```
class X {};

void foo()
{
    sptr_wrapper<X> x;
    boost::shared_ptr<X> y;

    x.set_from_sptr(y);
}
```

And this produces the compilation errors you were looking for:

```
t.C:27:14: error: request for member ‘sptr’ in ‘(sptr_wrapper<X>*)this’, which is of pointer type ‘sptr_wrapper<X>*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
   27 |         this.sptr = sptr; // (2)
```

Note that merely instantiating

```
    sptr_wrapper<X> x;
```

isn't enough. You have to go full throttle and invoke the method in question, before it becomes "real" in the eyes of a C++ compiler, and it chokes on it.

It's true that I can quite think of any circumstance where "this.foo" might be valid C++ code, but I'm sure that somewhere in the 2000 pages that make up the current C++ standard, the exact details of what's going on gets spelled out in a very pedantic way.

And you might consider dropping a note to your compiler's bug tracker, a feature request to have your compiler issue a friendly warning, in advance, when it sees something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Yes, it would be nice to have templates pre-parsed and a warning issued.

Comment: @LukeHutchison This will be possible in C++20 (it's a feature called "concepts".)

Answer (score 3):

The line `(2)` is invalid. As you said, `this` is a pointer, we need to use `->` instead of `.`

As the member of [class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template), `sptr_wrapper::set_from_sptr` is not required to be instantiated, until it's used. So you can add some code trying to call it, then you might get compile-errors as you expect.

> This applies to the members of the class template: unless the member is used in the program, it is not instantiated, and does not require a definition.

---

The line `(3)` is valid; `sptr` refers to the member `sptr`, which has the same effect as [`this->sptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this).

> When a non-static class member is used in any of the contexts where the this keyword is allowed (non-static member function bodies, member initializer lists, default member initializers), the implicit **`this->`** is automatically added before the name, resulting in a member access expression (which, if the member is a virtual member function, results in a virtual function call).